# What are the benefits with TearDown() and Setup() function?

Tags: c++, googletest

I am using `gtest` and `gmock` in my applications and I couldn't able to understand the purpose of `Setup()` and `Teardown()` functions in `gtest`. 
As per my understanding `Setup()` function will be called before each `TEST_F` execution and `Teardown()` will be called at the end. We can use the `::testing::Test` class `constructor` and `destructor` for the same purpose right? Where exactly these function are used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these functions to (re-)establish a certain state of resources that are shared among all of your test cases. Especially in case when exceptions are involved in your test cases.

From their [documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/FAQ.md#should-i-use-the-constructordestructor-of-the-test-fixture-or-the-set-uptear-down-function) it's said:

> You may still want to use SetUp()/TearDown() in the following rare cases:
>
> - If the tear-down operation could throw an exception, you must use `TearDown()` as opposed to the destructor, as throwing in a destructor leads to undefined behavior and usually will kill your program right away. Note that many standard libraries (like STL) may throw when exceptions are enabled in the compiler. Therefore you should prefer `TearDown()` if you want to write portable tests that work with or without exceptions.
> - The assertion macros throw an exception when flag `--gtest_throw_on_failure` is specified. Therefore, you shouldn't use Google Test assertions in a destructor if you plan to run your tests with this flag.
> - In a constructor or destructor, you cannot make a virtual function call on this object. (You can call a method declared as virtual, but it will be statically bound.) Therefore, if you need to call a method that will be overriden in a derived class, you have to use `SetUp()`/`TearDown()`.

Comment: can you please provide an example? we can share the resources by adding them into the test class right? if a resource is the part of Test class it will be shared among test functions, am I right?

Comment: 3rd point it is mean that SetUp() and TearDown() functions can be called from TEST_F function? I couldn't able to understand the 3rd point

Comment: @GilsonPJ Calling `virtual` functions require a fully constructed object instances of the test class, these can't be done inside a constructor body.

Comment: calling which virtual function? usually we are deriving the Test class and we will create the test class, which will not have any virtual functions.

Comment: That doesn't say you cannot have such generally.

Comment: Thank you so much for attending my question @ πάντα ῥεῖ . and thanks for the patience. I am still not understanding  your point. can you please provide me an example? I am not having much experiance with gtest

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ  thank you so much. After reading that documentation and your comments I got a clear idea. Thanks man!